# EF4.1 - Fluent API - SqlQuery - configuration mappings when calling sproc - Data reader is incompatible with specified entity type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-4.1, fluent-interface

The scenario - legacy application with 10 year history, has always used procedure calls for all data access - needs to be overhauled from a hybrid classic ASP and .NET set of pages.

The goal - migrate to .NET 4.0 using EF 4.1 with Fluent API and continue using existing database sprocs as much as possible.

Key classes:

```
public class EntityBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class User : EntityBase
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
...
}
```

Configurations:

```
internal class ConfigurationBase<T> : EntityTypeConfiguration<T> where T : EntityBase
{
    protected ConfigurationBase()
    {
        HasKey(t => t.Id);
    }
}

internal class UserConfiguration : ConfigurationBase<User>
{
    internal UserConfiguration()
    {
        Property(p => p.Id)
            .HasColumnName("Person_Id")
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
            .IsRequired();
        Property(p => p.UserName)
            .HasMaxLength(64);
        ToTable("Person");
    }
}
```

The context is all set up in DbContext.OnModelCreating as:

```
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserConfiguration());
    }
```

And all is fine when I access the data directly via the context eg:

```
    public override IQueryable<User> GetAll()
    {
        return UnitOfWork.Context.Users;
    }
```

But when I attempt to use an existing sproc which contains the following:

```
SELECT  p.Person_Id,
        p.IsUser,
        p.FirstName,
        p.LastName,
        p.UserName,
        p.Email,
        p.CreatedBy,
        p.CreatedDate,
        p.IsActive,
        p.ModifiedBy,
        p.ModifiedDate
FROM    Person p 
WHERE   p.UserName = @UserName
AND     p.IsActive = 1
```

I execute the following:

```
    public User AuthorizeUser(string userName)
    {
        SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter { 
            DbType = DbType.String,
            ParameterName = "UserName",
            Size = 64,
            Value = userName
        };
        object[] parameters = new object[] {p};

        return UnitOfWork.Context.Users.SqlQuery(CPODSStoredProcedures.User_AuthorizeUser, parameters).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

And I get:
The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'User'. A member of the type, 'Id', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

I have traced the execution and the configurations are being read, so am I doing something wrong, or is the sproc execution by SqlQuery not paying attention to how the base Id is remapped to Person_Id in this case.

Thanks in advance!
G

Comment: One thought occurred to me in the fog of sleep.  The Person class in this case is self-referencing.  UpdatedBy and CreatedBy are both foreign key references to itself.

When I get in the office I'll try running a similar sproc against a less complex class and see if the issue reoccurs.

Comment: Well I finally found time today to create a definitive test.  I created a standalone table with only two columns and created matching objects which derived from a base class that defined ID and mapped the ID to the table's ID column (Test_ID) in a configuration class.  Same result - same error.  Evidently the sproc call via SqlQuery ignores all that lovely Fluent-API configuration code and just looks for direct mappings.  So what do I do now?  *stumped*

Comment: I'm wondering if implementing custom materializers may be the answer - or if perhaps we should pursue a different architecture path in this app, since we have so many pre-existing sprocs to deal with and so far making EF work with them doesn't seem to be an easy task.

Comment: Seems more and more like my end solution will have to be changing all the sprocs to conform their output to what the POCOs define rather than what the configurations define.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF 4.1 Code First (ie: the fluent API you're trying to use) doesn't support Stored Procedures. [See here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/04/11/ef-4-1-released.aspx).

If you want to do this with EF, you have no choice but to create a model (or maybe wait until the next release). Personally I don't think that's a problem, because since the database already exists creating a model using DB First is really easy (point it at those tables and say "build this"). You can then switch EF to use the DbContext generator and get nice clean POCO classes to work with your data. [Here's a simple explanation on how to do that.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-model-amp-database-first-walkthrough.aspx)

I know the fluent API is the buzzword compliant shiny thing right now, but it's also brand new in this release of EF and not everything is there yet. With a legacy app it's going to save you a tremendous amount of headaches to simply use the DB First model and POCO class generators instead.

Comment: Well the sproc calls *work* if I change the sproc to match the name... that's the thing that has me frustrated.  But actually I'm not at ALL opposed to using the modeler (unlike some of my cohorts here) - I can tolerate having to refresh the model when the database changes.  Its the big fat heavy objects it produces I want to avoid.  Let me review the DbContext generator article - this may be JUST what I needed!

Comment: Agree totally about the "fat" objects, but I'm really happy with what the DbContext generator puts out. The classes are simple partial classes and much easier to work with. :)

Comment: FYI I haven't forgotten the bounty - I had almost no time today to continue pursuing this but I hope to be able to tomorrow.

Comment: Well, I was able to set up a simple model, but ultimately, I ended up with the same problem.  The entity User in the model is mapped so that Field "Id" has a column mapping to "Person_Id" in the Person data table, and my sproc is returning "Person_ID" - so EF *should* map the Person_Id in the data reader to Id in the object, but instead I get 'The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'Entity.User'. A member of the type, 'Id', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.'  That's basically the same problem as with fluent-api. :(

Comment: Wow that's really strange. :( If you map the procedure to the entity it's supposed to be able to handle something like that, so I'm not sure what to tell you here. :( When you mapped the procedure's output to the entity, did it have any options to force columns to specified values? (I haven't done it with SQL Server, I'm using the Oracle driver which is kind of quirky so I'm not sure how much help I can be.)

Comment: Well I ran into a problem there - I was able to map the procedure to a *collection* of entities, or to define a Complex type to map to - but I could not directly tell it to map to my User entity as a singular return value.  That surprised me - shouldn't I be able to have a sproc return just ONE instance of an entity?

Comment: You'd think so, yeah. I guess a collection isn't the end of the world if you know you're only getting one, as you can call First() or just get the first one in it afterward. Bit of a nuisance but it's not too horrible.

Comment: Ok - after reading your last comment I went back to the model and checked and I had NOT mapped the sproc to the column - I'd only mapped the entity to the column.  After mapping the individual sproc, the sproc did execute!   Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Mapping incompatible sproc (or transforming sproc result sets into new forms) to your object model is as easy as using a table var and sp_executesql as a batch provided in your call to DbContext.SqlQuery(). See my blog for a working example of this in action->

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/schlepticons/archive/2012/10/15/yes-you-can-execute-parameterized-sprocs-with-ef-fluent-api-code-only-and-more.aspx

Answer (score 1):

To execute a stored procedure in EF you need to create a function import. My company is in the same boat. We migrated to EF and have a billion procs that we need to keep using until some point when we deprecate them. EF actually makes it really easy to use stored procs through the use of function imports.

1. Go to Update Model from Database.
2. In the "Add" screen find the stored procedure you wish to use and check the box next to it.
3. Click finish.
4. Right-click the EF design surface and go to "Add" > "Function Import".
5. Choose the proc you wish to map.
6. Click "Get Column Information".
7. Click generate new "Complex Type". (or if you have an entity mapped, you can return an instance of the entity instead of the complex type.)
8. Click OK. You are done.

After adding a function import you will then have a method on your EF context object, e.g.:

```
EntityContainter context = new EntityContainer();
User user = context.AuthorizeUser(username);
```

I wrote a blog on this process, here: http://www.codetunnel.com/blog/post/53/how-to-map-a-stored-procedure-to-an-entity-in-entity-framework-4

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am not using the modeling tool.  I am using Fluent-API.

Comment: Ah okay. I have no experience with Fluent-API. I apologize. I do recommend you try out the tool however, as it supports stored procedures quite well.

Comment: Ok, compounded with Tridus' answer, I think I'm honing in on a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I abandoned EntityFramework for nHibernate a couple versions ago, but I am pretty sure your properties Id and UserName need to be flagged virtual, as with most POCOs used in ORMs, no?

Comment: Oh my goodness - if it's THAT simple and obvious I'm going to have to bang my head on a wall for a week.  Let me test it and get back to you!

Comment: I actually feel bad for posting such a simple answer, but I went ahead and did so because I have done this before... as well as forgetting to mark unit test classes public, which is also super-frustrating to track down.

Comment: Well, it was a good thought, and I had forgotten to add the virtual keyword, but even after adding it, the problem still exists.  :(  Sorry.

Comment: EF 4.1 POCO normal table properties don't have to be marked virtual. Navigation properties do though.